# Strange behavior with Laravel session data and Ajax request

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm completely stumped on this. I'm using Laravel 5.1.26. I have an index page that clear session data when visited:

```
Route::get('/', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
  $request->session()->flush();

  return view('index');
});
```

Within this view, I print out the session data to confirm it's cleared with these lines:

```
<pre>
<?php print_r(Session::all()); ?>
```

The output confirms the session is clear by showing `Array()`.

I have a second route that loads a view, and then makes an Ajax call to a third url:

Here is the second route and view:

**Route**

```
Route::get('tweeting', function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
  return view('tweeting');
});
```

**View**

```
<pre>
<?php print_r(Session::all()); ?>

@unless (Session::get('tweets_posted'))
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/tweet',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
      }
    }).done(function() {
      $('.done').show();
    }).fail(function() {
      $('.error').show();
    }).always(function() {
      $('.spinner').hide();
    });
  });
</script>
@endunless
```

As you can see, this view again prints out the session content and makes an ajax POST request to another route. That route is here:

```
Route::post('tweet', function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
  $request->session()->put('tweets_posted', true);
  return response()->json([]);
});
```

I'm trying to prevent the ajax call from being made again if the user reloads the `/tweeting` page, but allow the call again if they go back to the index page first, hence the call to `flush()` the session on the first route.

However, I'm finding that after the `tweets_posted` value is set in the session, it doesn't clear even after going back to the index page. Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. Visit '/', confirm session is empty
2. Visit '/tweeting', confirm ajax call is made
3. Visit '/', confirm session is empty
4. Visit '/tweeting', and notice that the session still contains 'tweets_posted' = true and therefore the Ajax call is not made.

Is anyone able to reproduce this or explain why it would be occurring?

I'm using the default session driver in case that is relevant.

**UPDATE**

What's even stranger, is as soon as I remove the call to set the `tweets_posted` session data in the third route. The problem goes away. Meaning, after completing the steps above to reproduce the problem a few times, if I change the third route to just:

```
Route::post('tweet', function(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
  return response()->json([]);
});
```

Then visit the `/` route followed by the `/tweeting` route, the session data is properly cleared.